# Text outputting below div

Tags: html, css

It works fine and is centred when the text is smaller, but for longer lines the text is outputted below the division

Below is the code. Its a div with 2 div side by side, where in the left div has an imp. I want text to be centred in the right div.

```html
<div style={{ height: '12rem',textAlign: 'center', lineHeight: '12rem', backgroundColor: '#edf2f4'}} className="shadow rounded">
  <div style={{width: '30%', float: "left", height: '10rem'}}>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1657299170964-205905bb0940?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80" style={{ width: '100%', height: '10rem', objectFit: 'contain'}} />
  </div>
  <div style={{ float: "left", paddingLeft: '2rem', overflow: 'auto'}}>
    <p>vhvhvhvvhvhv vhvhv vhvhvh hvhvhv vhvhv hvhvh hhbh hbhb hbhb bhbh hbhb bhbh bhbh bh bhvhv</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add style `text-align: center` on the text

```
<p style={{ text-align:"center"}}>vhvhvhvvhvhv vhvhv vhvhvh hvhvhv vhvhv hvhvh  hhbh hbhb hbhb bhbh hbhb bhbh bhbh bh bhvhv</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you use some other frameworks in your project, because the [normal way](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_style.asp) of using **inline style** is not similar to `style={{width: '30%', ... }}`. Any way I changed your styles to normal syntax and modify them like the code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        *, *::after, *::before {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<!-- "height: 12rem" is not enough for long text. you can set a longer height. so that the text is inside div.  -->
<div style="width: 100%; height: 45rem; background-color: #FFf204; text-align: center; line-height: 12rem">
  <div style="width: 30%; float: left; height: 10rem">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1657299170964-205905bb0940?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80" style="width: 100%; height: 10rem; object-fit: contain" />
  </div>
  <div style="float: left; padding-left: 2rem; overflow: auto; width: 70%">
    <p>vhvhvhvvhvhv vhvhv vhvhvh hvhvhv vhvhv hvhvh hhbh hbhb hbhb bhbh hbhb bhbh bhbh bh bhvhv vhvhvhvvhvhv vhvhv vhvhvh hvhvhv vhvhv hvhvh hhbh hbhb hbhb bhbh hbhb bhbh bhbh bh bhvhv vhvhvhvvhvhv vhvhv vhvhvh hvhvhv vhvhv hvhvh hhbh hbhb hbhb bhbh hbhb bhbh bhbh bh bhvhv vhvhvhvvhvhv vhvhv vhvhvh hvhvhv vhvhv hvhvh hhbh hbhb hbhb bhbh hbhb bhbh bhbh bh bhvhv</p>
  </div>
</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

In the above code I added some styles like adding `box-sizing: border-box;` in the `head` section and adding `width: 70%` for second `div`. But the main problem you mentioned (**text is outputted below the division**) comes from this fact that the `height: '12rem'` is not enough for **long text**. You can read [this article](https://www.lockedownseo.com/parent-div-100-height-child-floated-elements/) that helps you better understand the behavior of **float** styles. According to that article a better solution for your problem is using `overflow: auto;` like the code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        *, *::after, *::before {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<!-- use "overflow: auto;" and "height: auto;" to automatically set the height of the parent of float elements to 100%.  -->
<div style="width: 100%; height: auto; overflow: auto; background-color: #FFf204; text-align: center; line-height: 12rem">
  <div style="width: 30%; float: left; height: 10rem">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1657299170964-205905bb0940?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80" style="width: 100%; height: 10rem; object-fit: contain" />
  </div>
  <div style="float: left; padding-left: 2rem; overflow: auto; width: 70%">
    <p>vhvhvhvvhvhv vhvhv vhvhvh hvhvhv vhvhv hvhvh hhbh hbhb hbhb bhbh hbhb bhbh bhbh bh bhvhv vhvhvhvvhvhv vhvhv vhvhvh hvhvhv vhvhv hvhvh hhbh hbhb hbhb bhbh hbhb bhbh bhbh bh bhvhv vhvhvhvvhvhv vhvhv vhvhvh hvhvhv vhvhv hvhvh hhbh hbhb hbhb bhbh hbhb bhbh bhbh bh bhvhv vhvhvhvvhvhv vhvhv vhvhvh hvhvhv vhvhv hvhvh hhbh hbhb hbhb bhbh hbhb bhbh bhbh bh bhvhv</p>
  </div>
</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks I think the main problem is only one line is being outputted in the div. How do I ensure multiple lines are printed in the div

Comment: @kev b I could not understand your meaning! one line or multiple line depends on the length of text. Also the ```div```  itself has **relative width** that means the width is different in different window size. Could you explain your meaning more clearly?